# Java android code

Tags: java, android

Could you please explain this code by line to line?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See the JavaDoc of the method [`public View inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29):

> Inflate a new view hierarchy from the specified xml resource. Throws
>   InflateException if there is an error.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *resource*        ID for an XML layout resource to load (e.g., R.layout.main_page)
>   
>   *root*               Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy.
>   
>   **Returns**
>
> The root View of the inflated hierarchy. If root was supplied, this is the root View; otherwise it is the root
>   of the inflated XML file.